# Get the previous calculated record divided by group - SQL

Tags: sqlite, common-table-expression

I'm strugging to build two calculated columns (named `balance` and `avg`). My original SQLite base is:

```
name    seq side    price   qnt
groupA  1   B       30      100
groupA  2   B       36      200
groupA  3   S       23      300
groupA  4   B       30      100
groupA  5   B       54      400
                
groupB  1   B       70      300
groupB  2   B       84      300
groupB  3   B       74      600
groupB  4   S       90      100
```

Rational for the 2 calculated new columns:

**balance**: the first line of each group (seq = 1), must have the same value of `qnt`. The next records follow the below formula (Excel-based scheme):

```
if(side="B"; `previous balance record` + `qnt`; `previous balance record` - `qnt`)
```

**avg**: the first line of each group (seq = 1), must have the same value of `price`. The next records follow the below formula (Excel-based scheme):

```
if(side="B"; ((`price` \* `qnt`) + (`previous balance record` \* `previous avg record`)) / (`qnt` + `previous balance record`); `previous avg record`)
```

Example with numbers (the second row of groupA is calculated below):

```
--> balance: 100 + 200 = 300
--> avg: ((36 * 200) + (100 * 30)) / (200 + 100) = 34
```

I think this problem must be solved with CTE because I need the previous record, which is in being calculated every time.

I wouldn't like to aggregate groups - my goal is to display every record.

Finally, this is what I expect as the output:

```
name    seq side    price   qnt     balance avg
groupA  1   B         30    100     100     30
groupA  2   B         36    200     300     34
groupA  3   S         23    300     0       34
groupA  4   B         30    100     100     30
groupA  5   B         54    400     500     49,2
                            
groupB  1   B         70    300     300     70
groupB  2   B         84    300     600     77
groupB  3   B         74    600     1200    75,5
groupB  4   S         90    100     1100    75,5
```

Thank you in advance!

Here is my dbfiddle test: https://dbfiddle.uk/TSarc3Nl

I tried to explain part of the coding (commented) to make things easier.

Comment: Can this first row ever have side=s?

Comment: Please add the calculations to each row of your output. To show exactly which values are used in your calculations.

Comment: @MatBailie let's assume the first row will always have side=B. The calculations of each rows: all fields are given numbers, except `balance` and `avg` - these are calculated. I explained the maths in a Excel-base scheme inside the question but I'll try to improve with numbers to make things easier.

Comment: Please add these calculations to your expected output, on each row. Not just one row example.

Comment: I'm interpreting this as Bought and Sold, and you want AVG to be the average of the Bought prices. If that's the case, I think your formula is wrong. Take a look at these two different variants of a weighted average for the price of B. https://dbfiddle.uk/4ess8O2w (My weighted average is what I think is correct, and doesn't require recursion, so will be MUCH quicker.)

Comment: I got your point but pay attention on your variant: the avg 33 for `groupA - seq 4` is incorrect. The previous info (seq 3) shows that I have no more stocks (balance = 0). In this way, the correct `avg` for row number 4 is the `price` itself (avg = 30). Do you agree?

Comment: I agree that my formula gives a different result. But as I have said; it is not remotely clear what your formula is "supposed" to be doing. So, my answer below implements your formula, and my comment above challenges whether your formula is correct. Unless you describe the functional intent of your formula, there is no possible way for me to validate or challenge it. That's why my comment describes what I think is the purpose of the avg column.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to calculate in `avg field` the weighted average but not only for buying side. Always when it happens a sell, the avg does not change (it repeates value from the previous one), only the balance does change. For the next operation, we need to calculate the weighted average again. If it's a buy, we should taking into account the current value (price * qnt) plus the previous values (balance * avg), dividing by the sum (qnt + balance).

Comment: You just repeated WHAT your calculation is, not WHY you're calculating it that way. For example, I calculated the weighted average price of stock ever bought. You ***seem*** to be calculating the weighted average of stock still in your possession. But, it ***only*** seems to make sense when you sell ALL stock (the previous average gets weighted by zero and so gets ignored). If you sell PART of the stock the calculation makes no sense to me. For example, in your last row you sell 100 @ 90 each, if the next row is to buy 100 for the same price you sold at (90 each), why does avg go up???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The balance can be derived from a cumulative sum (using a case expression for when to deduct instead of add).

Then the recursive part just needs a case expression of its own.

```
WITH
  adjust_table AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    SUM(
      CASE WHEN side='B'
           THEN qnt
           ELSE -qnt
      END
    ) 
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY name
            ORDER BY seq
      )
        AS balance
  FROM
    mytable
),
  recurse AS
(
  SELECT adjust_table.*, price AS avg FROM adjust_table WHERE seq = 1
 
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT
    n.*,
    CASE WHEN n.side='B'
         THEN ((n.price * n.qnt * 1.0) + (s.balance * s.avg)) / (n.qnt + s.balance)
         ELSE s.avg
    END
      AS avg
  FROM
    adjust_table   n
  INNER JOIN
    recurse        s
      ON  n.seq  = s.seq + 1
      AND n.name = s.name
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  recurse
ORDER BY
  name,
  seq
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/mWz945pG

Though I'm not sure what the avg is meant to be doing, so it's possible I got that wrong and/or it could possibly be simplified to not need recursion.

NOTE: ***Never*** use `,` to join tables.

---

***EDIT:*** Recursion-less version

Use window functions to accumulate the balance, and also the total spent.

Then, use that to a enable the use of another window function to accumulate how much 'spend' is being 'recouped' by sales.

Your avg is then the adjusted spend divided by the current balance.

```
WITH
  accumulate AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    SUM(
      CASE WHEN side='B' THEN qnt ELSE -qnt END
    ) 
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY name
            ORDER BY seq
      )
        AS balance,
    1.0
    *
    SUM(
      CASE WHEN side='B' THEN price * qnt END
    )
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY name
            ORDER BY seq
      )
        AS total_spend
  FROM
    mytable
)
SELECT
  *,
  (
    total_spend
    -
    SUM(
      CASE WHEN side='S'
           THEN qnt * total_spend / (balance+qnt)
           ELSE 0
      END
    )
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY name
            ORDER BY seq
      )
        -- cumulative sum for amount 'recouped' by sales
  ) 
  / NULLIF(balance, 0)
      AS avg
FROM
  accumulate
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/O0HEr556

Note: I still don't understand why you're calculating the avg price this way, but it matched your desired results/formulae, without recursion.

Comment: Brilliant! Really nice and complete answer! I've been studying your code and I think I have no question - that's is exactly what I've been looking for! Thank you so much!! I'm only sorry I don't have enough reputation to caste vote in your answer!